# OnAppearing is not called on current page when popup page is popped?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi I'M new in xamarin forms , OnAppearing is not called on current page when popup page is popped ... please how i can send data back form pupop page to the current page

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an MVVM framework [like FreshMvvm](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm).

Use ReverseInit method on the page model to retrieve info passed back from the popup page.